# Ways to set request status from open to closed

Tags: status

I'm working on requests functionality and there can be 2 statuses of a request: open and closed.
Every request has certain steps a user has to complete and once they do, the request will close automatically.
It should be possible to close a request before completing all the steps. Also we will not let users reopen closed requests.

---

[image: Open request]

**The first** solution was to use a dropdown and then I realised there will only be 2 options :(
Both are really weird, especially because we can't reopen requests

**The second** thought was to add a close request button, which becomes too visible and I'm afraid users might click that before completing all the steps without a reason.

[image: dropdowns]

[image]

I'm wondering if there are other possible solutions I am missing? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to get rid of the drop down, as the user cannot change options as they please. Moving from "open" to "closed" is a one-time action, and cannot be reversed.

I recommend that the current status is just shown as a label (with colour if you wish). If the current status is set to "open", then show a link that allows the user to close the current request - make it as clear as possible what the link does.

Something like this:

[image]

The reason I have opted to use a link, rather than a button, is because the action is expected to be less common. Therefore, using a link makes the function more subtle, rather than having a big button that is just begging to be clicked.

---

Of course, as this is an irreversible action, you need to ensure that you prompt for confirmation when the user clicks the link. This can be a simple yes/no dialog box. If you want the user to be *extra* sure they are agreeing to close it, then you could add an additional checkbox to the confirmation dialog.

For example:

[image]

The user is then forced to "acknowledge" the action before they can confirm (as the button is initially disabled). This added step effectively forces the user to stop and think about what they are doing - as opposed to just being able to click buttons without reading the message.

I would argue it is probably overkill for this particular feature, and is better server for actions such as permanently deleting something. However, I wanted to give you the option if you think it is required or not. You could just have the dialog without the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why link is important to design it as a link and why it needs to be subtle. Good Observation! To add to that, there can be a text button or a secondary button added that would still serve the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like your combining the "status" and "actions" together.
The Requester should have an action of "Cancel Request' the status then becomes closed.